# JQuery .offset() doesn't set 'top' value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I am attempting to dynamically set a div's offset to four different positions;

- Top Left
- Top Right
- Bottom Left
- Top Right

my current solution relies on the .position() of an input element. However, after using .css() and .offset(), I am only able to set the 'left' offset but not the 'top', quite bizarre.

```
var position_picker = function () {
    const container = $(".np-container");
    const pos = $("#NumberPicker").position();

    switch (position) {
        case "top-left":
            top = pos.top;
            left = pos.left;
            container.addClass("top-left");
            break;
        case "top-right":
            top = parseInt(container.height());
            left = parseInt($("#NumberPicker").width()) - parseInt(container.width()) + pos.left;
            container.addClass("top-right");
            break;
        case "bottom-right":
            top = pos.top + parseInt($("#NumberPicker").height());
            left = parseInt($("#NumberPicker").width()) - parseInt(container.width()) + pos.left;
            container.addClass("bottom-right");
            break;
        default:
            top = pos.top + parseInt($("#NumberPicker").css("height"));
            left = pos.left;
            container.addClass("bottom-left");
            break;
    }

    $(".np-container").offset({
        top: top + parseInt($("#NumberPicker").css("marginTop")),
        left: left + parseInt($("#NumberPicker").css("marginLeft"))
    })
}
```

The `$(".np-container")` is the element I am attempting to dynamically position, while the `$("#NumberPicker")` is the input which it is to rely on for its offset.

The CSS for `$(".np-container")` is as follows

```
.np-container {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

    .np-container:before {
        content: '';
        border: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #ddd;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .np-container > .np-body {
        padding: 5px 3px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: can you also give us the css?

Comment: @Ivan css been included, not sure it's relevant - apart from `position: absolute;`. The `.np-container` is visible on focus of an input.

Answer (score 0):

Still not too sure what had caused this, though I used a different method to achieve what I needed;

```
    var position = element.position();
    var offset = element.offset();

    if (options.position === "auto") {
        options.position =
            (offset.top + widget.height() * 1.5 >= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() &&
                widget.height() + element.outerHeight() < offset.top)
            ? "top"
            : "bottom";
        options.position += (parent.width() < offset.left + widget.outerWidth() / 2 &&
                offset.left + widget.outerWidth() > $(window).width())
            ? "-right"
            : "-left";
    }
```

Found some magic that took into consideration the input elements position and set the pickers position relevant to the window.

```
    switch (options.position) {
        case "top-left":
            obj = {
                top: position.top - widget.outerHeight() - element.outerHeight(),
                left: (parent === element ? 0 : position.left),
            };
            widget.addClass("top-left");
            break;
        case "top-right":
            obj = {
                top: position.top - widget.outerHeight() - element.outerHeight(),
                left: position.left - (widget.outerWidth() - element.outerWidth()),
            };
            widget.addClass("top-right");
            break;
        case "bottom-left":
            obj = {
                top: position.top + element.outerHeight(),
                left: (parent === element ? 0 : position.left),
            };
            widget.addClass("bottom-left");
            break;
        case "bottom-right":
            obj = {
                top: position.top + element.outerHeight(),
                left: position.left - (widget.outerWidth() - element.outerWidth()),
            };
            widget.addClass("bottom-right");
            break;
    }
```

My switch statement used different logic but keeps the same structure.

```
    margins = {
        top: parseInt(element.css("marginTop")) === NaN ? 0 : parseInt(element.css("marginTop")),
        bottom: parseInt(element.css("marginBottom")) === NaN ? 0 : parseInt(element.css("marginBottom")),
        left: parseInt(element.css("marginLeft")) === NaN ? 0 : parseInt(element.css("marginLeft")),
        right: parseInt(element.css("marginRight")) === NaN ? 0 : parseInt(element.css("marginRight"))
    }

    obj.top += obj.top !== "auto" ? margins.top + margins.bottom : "";
    obj.left += obj.left !== "auto" ? margins.left - margins.right : "";
    obj.bottom = "auto";
    obj.right = "auto";

    widget.css(obj);
```

Finally I take into account the margins as before, but set the `.css()` with the built up *obj* object.